# Evaluating the integral:$\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx$$

put $\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)=y^{1/n}$

$$I=\frac{\ln10}{2n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty10^{-y^{1/n}}y^{1/n}dy$$

put $10^{-y^{1/n}}=e^{-t}\implies$

$$I=\frac1{(2\ln10)^n}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-t}t^ndt+\frac1{(2\ln10)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^ndt$$

$$I=\frac1{(2\ln10)^n}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-t}t^ndt+\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(2\ln10)}$$

I want to know how can I evaluate the first integral in the last step of my turn I used some substitutions so i get two integrals one of them converted to the formula of gamma function but the second could not be so because the domain of integration is different ?
$n$ is a natural number

Comment: are you sure that your integral converges?

Comment: Of course not sure

Comment: Please do not repost!

Comment: I reposted it because there was a missing in the qusetion @Simply Beatiful Art

Comment: @HussienMohamed Then edit your previous question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right) =-2\log\left(x\right)$$
ie 
$$I=\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx =\int_0^\infty x\left(-2\log\left(x\right)\right)^n dx$$
Now set 
$u =-2\log\left(x\right)$ i.e $ x= e^{-\frac{u}{2}}$ which implies $$~~u\to \infty ~~~as~~~ x\to 0^+$$ and  $$u\to \infty ~~~as~~ x\to \infty$$ and

$$dx  = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{u}{2}}du $$

then $$ I = -\frac{1}{2} \int^{-\infty}_\infty e^{-\frac{u}{2}}u^ne^{-\frac{u}{2}}du =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u}u^n ~du \\=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^\infty e^{-u}u^n ~du +\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-u}u^n ~du =\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(n+1)+\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u}u^n ~du $$

But $$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-u}u^n ~du =(-1)^n\int_{0}^\infty e^{u}u^n ~du $$ 
does not converge .
Since  $u>0\implies >e^u>1\implies u^ne^u>u^n$ that is

$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{u}u^n ~du>\int_{0}^\infty u^n ~du =\infty $$

> Hence $$I=\int_0^\infty x\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^n dx $$ Does not exist.

Comment: How can i show that the last integral does not converge ? @Guy Fsone

Comment: see that , $u>0\implies >e^u>1\implies u^ne^u>u^n$